# cassandra how to return generated unique key to server?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

In cassandra, when I insert a new piece of data I can generate a unique id using now() or uuid() depending on what kind of data type it is.
However, upon insertion success, is there anyway I can let the server (the web  server which send this insertion request) to know what unique id has been generated?
I do need it!

Comment: Since the client issued the insert command, it can query back using the primary key and get the data.

Comment: Generate UUID from the application layer and insert the generated UUID

Comment: It might not work in my case because I actually need a timeuuid to make sure every row is sorted by the order. If I generate timeuuid on server and not database, it is not guaranteed in this asychronos environment that I will always insert them in order. Also generating timeuuid that is not duplicated on server is a hard question itself...
But thanks anyway!